# How to make a value show up?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a a simple form to calculate my client's services. I want to make a function that adds up the services' values and show them right away without clicking in the button. I have no idea where I'm wrong.

```
<p>In total: <span id="number"></span></p>
<script>


  var kilometry = document.getElementById("kilom").value;
  var DoSto = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
  var OdSto = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
  var z = (+kilometry*2.5) + (+DoSto*20) + (+OdSto*80);
  var x = document.getElementById("number");
  x.innerHTML = z.value;

  z.oninput = function() {
    x.innerHTML = this.value;
  }




</script>
```

Can you explain why it doesnt work? smh

Comment: Why did you tag this as Java?

Comment: Please hit `f12` and read any console errors present.

Comment: Similarly, please provide all your `HTML`, the elements `kilom`, `myRange1` and `myRange2` are referenced, but the HTML associated with this is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable z is not an input element. It is a number. So you cannot access .value or .oninput on that variable.

So in that regard. This..

```
x.innerHTML = z.value;
```

Should be..

```
x.innerHTML = z;
```

And I guess you want the value in the x tag to update in realtime? You need to add event listeners to all the input elements you use to calculate the z variable.

So that means the following code..

```
 z.oninput = function() {
     x.innerHTML = this.value;
 }
```

can be rewritten as..

```
function calculateZ() {
    var z = (+kilometry*2.5) + (+DoSto*20) + (+OdSto*80);
    x.textContent = z; // x.innerHTML = z; works as well, but is less safe.
}

// Triggers when changing the value in the kilom, myRange1 and myRange2 input tags
document.getElementById("kilom").addEventListener('change', calculateZ);
document.getElementById("myRange1").addEventListener('change', calculateZ);
document.getElementById("myRange2").addEventListener('change', calculateZ);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running immediately and once only. You need to introduce an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) that occurs each time you change the value of an input.

```
<p>In total: <span id="number"></span></p>
<input id="kilom" onchange=calculateTotal()>
<input id="myRange1" onchange=calculateTotal()>
<input id="myRange2" onchange=calculateTotal()>
<script>
  function calculateTotal() {
    var kilometry = document.getElementById("kilom").value;
    var DoSto = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
    var OdSto = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
    var z = (+kilometry*2.5) + (+DoSto*20) + (+OdSto*80);
    var x = document.getElementById("number");
    x.innerHTML = z;
  }
</script>
```

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  var kilometry = document.getElementById("kilom").value;
  var DoSto = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
  var OdSto = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
  var z = (+kilometry*2.5) + (+DoSto*20) + (+OdSto*80);
  var x = document.getElementById("number");
  x.innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<p>In total: <span id="number"></span></p>
<input id="kilom" onchange=calculateTotal()>
<input id="myRange1" onchange=calculateTotal()>
<input id="myRange2" onchange=calculateTotal()>
```